# How create trigger in Django Rest Framework to change booleanfield?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a question in django rest framework. Since I'm learning how to use some advanced options, I do not quite understand. I need to currently change a  booleanfield every time a foreignkey is inserted into table. 
How can I do this in model ?

**Model:**

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Credit,null=True)
    rg = models.IntergerField()
    end = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    details = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart

    class Meta:
        db_table='person'
        app_label = 'bank'


class Credit(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField()
    available = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'credit'
        app_label = 'bank'
```

**Serializer:**

```
class PersonaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order__id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='order.id')


    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        fields = '__all__'


class Persona(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    allowed_methods = ('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH')
    queryset = Persona.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonaSerializer
```

Comment: It will be better if you explain more detail what you want to do step by step

Comment: @marcell-erasmus, I want to update the "available" field from false to true. However this will only be true, when in the Person table a pk of the credit table has been inserted. 
I thought it would be better to do the model, but how can I do it?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you haw to handle this in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `create` method on the `ModelSerializer` to achieve this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    cart = validated_data['cart']
    persona = super(PersonaSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
    cart.available = True # update boolean
    cart.save()
    return persona
```

You can read more about this in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

If you want to handle this in your model you can override the Persona model `save` method:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Credit,null=True)
    rg = models.IntergerField()
    end = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    details = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart

    class Meta:
        db_table='person'
        app_label = 'bank'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Will only update the available field when the Persona
        # instance is created and the cart field is not null
        if not self.pk and self.cart:
            self.cart.available = True
            self.cart.save()
        return super(Persona, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```